# Click an img on react to redirect to another component

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-router

I am trying to click on an image of the product, and redirect to a product show page to show the specific product. I am using ruby on rails as backend.

```
  render(){
    
    const {loading, error, products} = this.state
    // console.log("CHECK Render PRODUCT", this.state)
    if (error){
      return <p>Error loading</p>
    }
  
    const productsList = products.map(p => 
        <li key={p.id}>
        name: {p.name} <br />
        description: {p.description} <br />
        price: {p.price} <br />
        stock: {p.stock} <br/>
        <Link to={`./products/${p.id}`}>
          <img className="product_image" src={`http://localhost:3000/assets/${p.image}`} alt={p.name} />
        </Link>
    </li>
    )
```

this is in my Products.js file. It seems like the `link to` doesn't work? How do I fix this?